# Is user's breakdown of votes per Q/A available on Data Explorer?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, voting, data-explorer

I can get total UVs and total DVs of the user from Data Explorer:

```
select UpVotes,DownVotes from Users where DisplayName='sjl'
-- user randomly picked from the first SE tab I had open, as long as not myself
1899       5
```

However, on user's page, I can see a more fine-grained breakdown of which votes were for questions vs. answers for the same user:

```
all time        by type                 month       week     
1,916  up       807     question        18      17  
5   down        1,114   answer
```

Is the latter breakdown (Qs vs As) available via Data Explorer somehow?

I'm trying to see if total user rep affects whether people upvote or downvote Qs vs As more (in other words, does -1 penalty have different effect as rep rises) as well as generally see if there are any interesting patterns in Q vs A voting

Comment: I don't think that is available because if it is not on the user entity you should  get it from the votes tables. For up and downvotes the userid is empty in the votes entity because voting is anonymouys.

Comment: @rene But this is publicly available information. For example you have 687 votes on questions and 431 on answers

Comment: @RichardTingle - exactly. That's why I included my second quote and specified in the first quote that the user I picked was NOT me.

Comment: The answer is "No", but that's not particularly interesting, so I assume you probably want to turn this into a request for that kind of information to be available.