# How to identify "questions upvoted" and "answers downvoted" in SEDE?

Tags: discussion, voting, data-explorer

In this query:

```
DECLARE @PERCENT float = ##PERCENTUPVOTES##
DECLARE @MIN_VOTES int = ##MINVOTES##


SELECT 
  id as [User Link], 
  Reputation,
  UpVotes,
  DownVotes,
  (1.0*UpVotes/(1.0*UpVotes+1.0*DownVotes)) as PercentUp

from USERS

where 
  UpVotes>0 and 
  (1.0*UpVotes/(1.0*UpVotes+1.0*DownVotes)) > @PERCENT/100.0 and
  (UpVotes+DownVotes) > @MIN_VOTES

order by UpVotes desc
```

I would like to also include columns for by question/answer, as can be seen on a user profile:
[image]

However this doesn't seem to be in the Users table in the data explorer. Is it possible to get this information?

Comment: No, that information isn't available for regular users. I think (not 100% sure) that this is a duplicate: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/220089/is-users-breakdown-of-votes-per-q-a-available-on-data-explorer